# Collapsing toolbar is not scrolling smoothly when tab changed - only support library 26 & 27

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, nestedscrollview

I have collapsing toolbar with viewpager & tablayout. Viewpager contains NestedScrollView which contains some CardViews - however the content is not relevant.

So far so good.

However, since I changed support library from 25.4.0 to 27.0.2 I run into this problem:

The problem is that when I change a tab and then scroll down (Collapsing toolbar is collapsing) it is not smooth. I tried to downgrade to support library 26.0.2, but the problem still persist. I found out that last support library which doesnt contain this bug is 25.4.0.

You can see a difference on this [video](https://youtu.be/mDYmAZJwC8M).

(Left side - 25.4.0 - smooth vs. right side - 27.0.2 (not smooth))

And this is how fragment inside viewpager looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/vTabContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The content doesnt matter the bug is still occuring no matter what is inside NestedScrollView -->
    <LinearLayout

    <!-- Some content...       -->

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

This is how activity looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/vDrawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/vCoordinator"
        style="@style/Layout.Coordinator"
        tools:context="io.stepuplabs.settleup.ui.circles.CirclesActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/vAppBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_behavior="io.stepuplabs.settleup.ui.AppBarBehavior"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/vCollapsingToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/collapsing_toolbar_height"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:titleEnabled="false"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/vSomething"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="none"
                     />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/vToolbar"
                    style="@style/Layout.Toolbar"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

                    <!-- It has to be ellipsized to fit vToolbar width in single line.-->
                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:id="@+id/vWhoShouldPayTitle"
                        style="@style/TextView"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="start"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/ActionbarTitle" />
                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/vTabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
                    app:tabMode="scrollable" />

            </io.stepuplabs.settleup.ui.circles.SmoothAnimatedCollapsingToolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <!-- This wrapping is needed otherwise ViewPager doesn't initialize pages -->
        <FrameLayout
            style="@style/Layout.Full"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/vBottomPager"
                style="@style/Layout.Full" />
        </FrameLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/vNavigationDrawer"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/include_drawer_header"
        app:itemBackground="@color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/gray_8"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/gray_8"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/ListPrimaryTiny"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I need some feautures which are in new support library so I can't simply downgrade back to 25.4.0. Thanks for help !